# Display an onClick button in Sweet Alert 2

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to assign OnClick to a button in  Sweet Alert 2 library

Ex :

```
 <Button onClick={signIn}> Sign In !</Button>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Checkout this link https://chentsulin.github.io/sweetalert-react/

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this

```js
const App = () => {
   const signIn = () => { 
     Swal.fire("Signed in");
   };
 
   return <button onClick={signIn}>Sign In!</button>  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: no I wanted to say that the onclick login button is displayed in the alert